# Can we run a .sh file as root from an APK

Tags: android

I need to run an .sh file that starts a process in background as root from an APK, but couldn't do it. Even when I use su it gives the APP level permissions. Here is my .sh fule contents

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su
/data/local/server port&
```

I used the following to run the sh but I couldn't get root permissions.

```
    try
     {
         Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
         Process proc = rt.exec("su");  

         proc = rt.exec("sh /sdcard/server.sh");             

     }catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I did some research but couldn't find any useful information and I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command through su you need to do

```
su -c '/data/local/server port&'
```

instead of

```
su
/data/local/server port&
```

Another question is how you gonna deal with authentication, but I suppose you've solved this already (you probably need to have hacked android OS image or something).

Comment: As long as the device has suid su binary, typically installed when you root a device this should work. The user will get a message to authorize your app to run a command as root, so the app should be able to handle the case when they deny it.

Comment: I have used the SuperUser.apk and the su file that comes with it to get the root access to the device. Thanks you for the input!

Comment: I see, so you basically need rooted device as stated in http://androidsu.com/superuser/ to make this work. Interesting, didn't know it, thanks!